# May Sharepoint 2010 portal combine intranet and extranet sites with different security models?

Tags: authentication, sharepoint-2010

There is Sharepoint 2010 intranet portal with several intranet sites based on Active directory user access. Is it possible to create one more site with quite different security model for Internet access or should I create standalone portal for Internet users? What shall I consider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have different authentication models at "Web Application" level. This means that all your site collections inside your Web Application will work with the same authentication model.
If you already have a web application working with Active Directory and you want to provide Internet Access (probably using Forms Authentication) you will need to create  a separate Web Application.

Here is a sample Video on how to create a new Web Application:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Z8vb42j1wQ

And this is a video on how to implement Forms Authentication a Web Application:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yBqL3E-ne60

Comment: Thank you, Dalorzo. Do I understand correctly that I have to create another instance of Sharepoint installation?

Comment: No, it is not a new instance of SharePoint but instead you have to go to the Central Administration and create a new "Web Application"